# Replace without Boost

Tags: c++, xml, replace, tags, strip

I have to strip some XML tags from the text and leave their values.

Example

```
text text <tag>tag_value</tag> text text <a href="example.com">example.com</a>
->
text text tag_value text text example.com
```

So far, I've used boost_replace but now I am not able to use that library.

```
std::string src(text);
std::string fmt ="";
std::string ex = "(<tag attribute=\"(.*?)\">)|(</tag>)|(<a href(.*?)\">)|(</a>)|(<tag>)|(</tag>))";
boost::regex expr(ex);
std::string s2 = boost::regex_replace(src, expr, fmt, boost::match_default | boost::format_all);
```

How could I solve that problem? What library could help me do that? Thanks

Comment: If you not able to use Boost, what are criteria of your library selection (e.g. what libraries are unacceptable too)?

Comment: Just 'light-weight' are acceptable

Comment: What is unacceptable about Boost? In the final executable, you will only have the parts of Boost that you actually use, which is all that you should really care about. You don't have to have any users download some 600+ MB file so that they have "all of Boost".

Comment: To be fair, my workplace has also banned Boost because it is "not lightweight." When you distribute that much source in a monolithic bundle and it isn't easily separable, that's an easy reputation to get.

Answer (score 1):

Never use regular expressions to parse XML!

See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You need a real XML library like expat or libxml2.

Comment: Question was about *stripping* tags without any further processing. It's ok to use regexps here.

Comment: It's still relevant. Throw a `<[[CDATA` in there or a `<!--` comment block and watch regexes collapse.

Comment: Ok, right, there is no simple regexp solution for stripping, however, I still think it's overkill *here* to use full-blown parser.

Comment: The OP did not say whether the XML comes from a known trusted source or not. So we have to assume that the XML could come from anywhere, and could contain things we don't expect. 

If you control the XML completely, from generation to parsing, and we're okay with not being fully XML compliant in our parser, then sure, we can compromise. But honestly, why recommend the half-assed approach? Let's do it right.

Comment: by the way the boost counterpart for this is boost::spirit

Comment: If anything you'd want a `boost::property_tree`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.xml_parser